# Error: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The following exception was thrown when I tried moving from my home page to the product page. I guess the exception was thrown because of the use of the list view. Could you please help me find the correct way to use it?

It should look something like this:

[image]

But instead, it's showing me errors

========
Exception caught by rendering library
=====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

```
    These invalid constraints were provided to RenderDecoratedBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
      RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
    The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=263.7, h=Infinity)
    The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      Container file:///C:/Users/bhask/Downloads/your_store/lib/screens/product_page.dart:143:36
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure>.throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:517:9)
    #1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:561:21)
    #2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:565:6)
    #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1679:24)
    #4      RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:277:14)
    ...
    The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderConstrainedBox#cef26 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    ...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
    ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=263.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    ...  size: MISSING
    ...  additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=65.0, h=Infinity)
    RenderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#cef26 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=263.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
      size: MISSING
      additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=65.0, h=Infinity)
    ...  child: RenderDecoratedBox#003df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    ...    parentData: <none>
    ...    constraints: MISSING
    ...    size: MISSING
    ...    decoration: BoxDecoration
    ...      color: Color(0xff000000)
    ...      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)
    ...    configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#dc45b(), devicePixelRatio: 2.8, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
    ...    child: RenderParagraph#fda35 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
    ...      parentData: <none>
    ...      constraints: MISSING
    ...      size: MISSING
    ...      textAlign: start
    ...      textDirection: ltr
    ...      softWrap: wrapping at box width
    ...      overflow: clip
    ...      locale: en_US
    ...      maxLines: unlimited
    ...      text: TextSpan
    ...        debugLabel: ((((englishLike body1 2014).merge(blackMountainView bodyText2)).copyWith).copyWith).merge(unknown)
    ...        inherit: false
    ...        color: Color(0xffffffff)
    ...        family: Poppins_regular
    ...        familyFallback: Poppins
    ...        size: 16.0
    ...        weight: 600
    ...        baseline: alphabetic
    ...        decoration: TextDecoration.none
    ...        "Add To Cart"
    ====================================================================================================
    
    ======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
    The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
    RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#cef26 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
    Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'
    
    
    Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
    In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
      https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md
    
    The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      Container file:///C:/Users/bhask/Downloads/your_store/lib/screens/product_page.dart:143:36
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1930:12)
    #3      RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:237:39)
    #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
    #5      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116:14)
    #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1779:7)
    ...
    The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderPadding#107a1 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    ...  parentData: <none> (can use size)
    ...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=279.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    ...  size: MISSING
    ...  padding: EdgeInsets(16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    ...  textDirection: ltr
    RenderObject: RenderPadding#107a1 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
      parentData: <none> (can use size)
      constraints: BoxConstraints(w=279.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
      size: MISSING
      padding: EdgeInsets(16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
      textDirection: ltr
    ...  child: RenderConstrainedBox#cef26 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    ...    parentData: offset=Offset(16.0, 0.0) (can use size)
    ...    constraints: BoxConstraints(w=263.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    ...    size: MISSING
    ...    additionalConstraints: BoxConstraints(w=65.0, h=Infinity)
    ...    child: RenderDecoratedBox#003df NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    ...      parentData: <none>
    ...      constraints: MISSING
    ...      size: MISSING
    ...      decoration: BoxDecoration
    ...        color: Color(0xff000000)
    ...        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)
    ...      configuration: ImageConfiguration(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#dc45b(), devicePixelRatio: 2.8, locale: en_US, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, platform: android)
    ...      child: RenderParagraph#fda35 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
    ...        parentData: <none>
    ...        constraints: MISSING
    ...        size: MISSING
    ...        textAlign: start
    ...        textDirection: ltr
    ...        softWrap: wrapping at box width
    ...        overflow: clip
    ...        locale: en_US
    ...        maxLines: unlimited
    ...        text: TextSpan
    ...          debugLabel: ((((englishLike body1 2014).merge(blackMountainView bodyText2)).copyWith).copyWith).merge(unknown)
    ...          inherit: false
    ...          color: Color(0xffffffff)
    ...          family: Poppins_regular
    ...          familyFallback: Poppins
    ...          size: 16.0
    ...          weight: 600
    ...          baseline: alphabetic
    ...          decoration: TextDecoration.none
    ...          "Add To Cart"
    ====================================================================================================
```

Here is my code for the products page:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_store/constants.dart';
import 'package:your_store/services/firebase_services.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/image_swipe.dart';
import 'package:your_store/widgets/product_size.dart';

class ProductPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? productId;
  ProductPage({this.productId});

  @override
  _ProductPageState createState() => _ProductPageState();
}

class _ProductPageState extends State<ProductPage> {

  FirebaseServices _firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();

  String? _selectedProductSize = "0";

  Future _addToCart() {
    return _firebaseServices.usersRef
        .doc(_firebaseServices.getUserId())
        .collection("Cart")
        .doc(widget.productId)
        .set({"size": _selectedProductSize});
  }

  final SnackBar _snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text("Product added to the cart."),);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          future: _firebaseServices.productRef.doc(widget.productId).get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                ),
              );
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              //Firebase document data map
             final documentData = snapshot.data!.data()!;

              //List of images
              List imageList = documentData["images"];
              List productSize = documentData["size"];

              //Set an initial size
              _selectedProductSize = productSize[0];

              return ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                children: [
                  ImageSwipe(
                    imageList: imageList,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 24.0,
                      left: 24.0,
                      right: 24.0,
                      bottom: 4.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      documentData["name"] ?? "",
                      style: Constants.boldHeading,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 4.0,
                      horizontal: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      documentData["price"] ?? "",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 8.0,
                      horizontal: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      documentData["desc"] ?? "",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 24.0,
                      horizontal: 24.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Select Size",
                      style: Constants.regularDarkText,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ProductSize(
                    productSize: productSize,
                    onSelected: (size){
                      _selectedProductSize = size;
                    },
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 65.0,
                          height: 65.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xFFDCDCDC),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Image(
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/tab_saved.png"),
                            height: 22.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              await _addToCart();
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(_snackBar);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              width: 65.0,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                left: 16.0,
                              ),
                              height: double.infinity,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                              child: Text(
                                "Add To Cart",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }

            //Loading State
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        CustomActionBar(
          hasBackArrow: true,
          hasTitle: false,
          hasBackground: false,
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe the listview inside stack is giving some weird sizes, try to use the parameter fit: Stackfit.passthrough or maybe you dont really need that Stack at all and can use your futurebuilder as body and CustomActionBar in bottomNavigationBar

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Could you implement it and show me once, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `Expanded` widget. First, you should not have an `Expanded` inside of a `ListView` unless the `Expanded` is the child of something that has a defined height, which yours is not. Also, your `ListView` is not even a child of a `Widget` with a defined height. Nothing in your Widget tree knows how tall it should be. You need to set a height for all the children of your `ListView`, especially the `Expanded` widget. `Padding` widgets do not have height, nor do `Row` widgets. You need to wrap one of the immediate parents of your `Expanded` in a `Container` or something with a specified height, otherwise it will keep expanding forever within the `ListView` and give you that `infinite height` error.

Side note: you set the height of your `Expanded`'s child to `double.infinity`, which is unecessary.

Edit:

This erroneous code:

```
ListView(
  //...
  children: [
    //...
    Padding(
      //...
      child: Row(
        children: [
          //...
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              //...
              height: double.infinity,
              child: Text('text'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

must become this:

```
ListView(
  //...
  children: [
    //...
    Container(
      height: 100.0, //or whatever you want
      width: 400.0, //or whatever you want
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      //...
      child: Row(
        children: [
          //...
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              //...
              child: Text('text'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

This is because `Expanded` searches up the widget tree, looking for a parent that tells it how large it is allowed to be. You haven't provided such a parent, which results in your error message. Now, this might not fix your problem entirely because there could be other elements in your `ListView` that have undefined heights. These will also cause errors because the `ListView` widget bases its height on the sum of its children's heights. If `ListView` doesn't know how tall each one of it's children are then it can't know how tall it should be and, again, you get that error message.

In conclusion, you need to look out for two things (not just here, but always):

1. All `Expanded` widgets have parents with defined heights
2. All children of `ListView` widgets have defined heights

It just so happens that you can solve both these problems by changing that `Padding` widget to a sized `Container`.

Comment: Hey! I've updated my question if you could have a look and help me by giving an example by implementing the changes in my code, please.

Comment: Thank you brother now it works completely fine.

Comment: Cool. Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

2 options

```
body: Stack(
  fit: Stackfit.passthrough,
  children: [
    .... //same code
  ],
),
```

OR

```
return Scaffold(
   body: FutureBuilder(
      .... ///same code
   ),
   bottomNavigationBar: CustomActionBar(
          hasBackArrow: true,
          hasTitle: false,
          hasBackground: false,
        ),
 );
```

Also as a sidenote this Scaffold is unnecesary

```
  return Scaffold( /// You can remove the scaffold and keep just Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
    body: Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ),
  );
```

Stack doesn't give the children a size to perform, so ListView tries an unbounded infinite size to perform its build method

Comment: Thanks but I don't know why it's not working for me. The error always sustains. I guess if you have a look at my code it might help you better. As I guess I'm not able to express myself well. Here is the code link. https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Final. The problem starts when you once log in and select a product or even on the search page if I try to search something.

Answer (score -1):

##### Please add ListView's shrinkWrap true.

```
return ListView(
       shrinkWrap: true,
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
       children: [
         ImageSwipe(
           imageList: imageList,
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
             top: 24.0,
             left: 24.0,
             right: 24.0,
             bottom: 4.0,
           ),
           child: Text(
             documentData["name"] ?? "",
             style: Constants.boldHeading,
           ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
             vertical: 4.0,
             horizontal: 24.0,
           ),
           child: Text(
             documentData["price"] ?? "",
             style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 18.0,
               color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
             ),
           ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
             vertical: 8.0,
             horizontal: 24.0,
           ),
           child: Text(
             documentData["desc"] ?? "",
             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
           ),
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
             vertical: 24.0,
             horizontal: 24.0,
           ),
           child: Text(
             "Select Size",
             style: Constants.regularDarkText,
           ),
         ),
         ProductSize(
           productSize: productSize,
           onSelected: (size){
             _selectedProductSize = size;
           },
         ),
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
           child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
             children: [
               Container(
                 width: 65.0,
                 height: 65.0,
                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   color: Color(0xFFDCDCDC),
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                 ),
                 alignment: Alignment.center,
                 child: Image(
                   image: AssetImage("assets/images/tab_saved.png"),
                   height: 22.0,
                 ),
               ),
               Expanded(
                 child: GestureDetector(
                   onTap: () async {
                     await _addToCart();
                     ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(_snackBar);
                   },
                   child: Container(
                     width: 65.0,
                     margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                       left: 16.0,
                     ),
                     height: double.infinity,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         color: Colors.black,
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                     child: Text(
                       "Add To Cart",
                       style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontSize: 16.0,
                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ],
     );
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything the problem remains the same as before.

Comment: Can you please replace Listview with Column and add mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I tried wrapping List view in column n passing mainAxisSize but the error still remains the same.

Comment: Not wrapping with Column Replace with Column and Column wrap with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know why it's not working for me. The error always sustains. I guess if you have a look at my code it might help you better. As I guess I'm not able to express myself well. Here is the code link https://github.com/Bhaskar2510/Final.  The problem starts when you once log in and select a product or even on the search page if I try to search something.